# Correr nodejs con php en conjunto

Tags: php, nodejs

Necesito usar nodejs junto a php.

He buscado en varios foros incluyendo **Stackoverflow** pero sigo sin lograrlo, mi proyecto básicamente esta hecho en php puro pero deseo utilizar websockets para poder implementar un módulo de mensajes y notificaciones en tiempo real.

Estoy usando Xampp para mi proyecto, ya coloqué la url proxy en Apache pero no logro que funcione. Por ejemplo `proxypass /nodejs` `http//localhost:3000/socket.io/` antes me decia `cannot get/` luego de poner el proxy me dice `cannot get/socket.io` el archivo es **index.php**

**NOTA:** si cambio la extensión del archivo a **index.html** me funciona a la perfeccion el chat en tiempo real y todo.

Adjunto coloco una imagen con el error que presento:

[image: este es el error que me muestrra el navegadoe]

y el código de mi práctica para lograr establecer conexion con nodejs y php:

**Mi sevidor en nodejs**

```
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const connect = require('connect');
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(3000);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//aqui estan los sockets desde otro archivo js para dejar el codigo de el servidor mas limpio
require('./socket')(io);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));


 //voy a establecer un puerto si no tomas el 3000
 app.set('port' , process.env.PORT || 3000)


//voy a recivir el puerto
server.listen(app.get('port') ,()=>{

    console.log('conectado con el servidor '+app.get('port'))
})
```

**Los sockets**

```
  module.exports= function(io){

    io.on('connection',socket=>{
    console.log('usuarios conectados con io');

    //esta es la accion que se recive desde el cliente
socket.on('mensaje-cliente',function (data) {

     console.log(data);
    //aqui el servidor la emite el mensaje a todos los clientes
    io.sockets.emit('mensaje-servidor', data);
})

 })

 }
```

**Mi index.html. Si lo cambio a index.php no funciona**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>chat websocket</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-primary">

   <a href="" class="navbar-brand mx-auto">WebsocketChat</a>

    </nav>
<div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-6 mt-4">
        <div class="card">

            <div class="card-header">
                <h4>lets Chat</h4>
            </div>

            <div id="chat" class="card-body">


            </div>

            <form class="card-footer" action="index.html" method="post" id="message-form">
                <div class="input-group">
                 <input type="text" name="" id="message" class="form-control">
                 <div class="input-group-append">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="" id="enviar">
                 </div>

            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    //ya intente cambiarlo a http://localhost:3000 pero nada de nada
  <script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**micliente main.js**

```
 $(function () {

   var socket=io();
//intente poner esta linea en el cliente pero tampoco
//var sockets = io.connect( 'http://localhost:' );

   //obteniendo los elementos del Dom 

   var formulario = $("#message-form");
   var mensajebox = $("#chat");
   var mensaje = $("#message");
   var enviar = $("#enviar");

    formulario.submit( e =>{

        e.preventDefault();
        //console.log(mensaje.val());

   //aquii con socket.io le damos un nombre al evento y capturamos el mensaje y *
        socket.emit('mensaje-cliente',mensaje.val());
        //limpiar input despues de enviar
           mensaje.val("");
    });

  /*aqui nos toca escuchar el mensaje atraves de la palabra clave del servidor*/

    socket.on('mensaje-servidor',function(data){

        //aqui elegimos donde mostrar el mensaje del servidor
        mensajebox.append(data+'<br>');
    });
})
```

Por favor si alguien es tan amable de ayudarme se lo agradeceria mucho. Cualquier tip o consejo de alguien que tenga experiencia en integrar nodejs con php es bien recibido.

Comment: nodejs no interpreta a php eso que intentas no es posible

Comment: es posible por que lo he visto e videos de youtube lo que pasa es que no lo explican como lo hacen

Comment: nop, en todo caso se hace un reverse proxy para que apache trabaje en conjunto con nodejs

Comment: Revisa [este enlace](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=es&js=y&prev=_t&hl=es&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fentwickler.de%2Fwebandphp%2Fintegrating-node-js-with-php-125830.html&edit-text=)

Comment: vale voy a checar gracias!